# Capistrano - can't deploy my database.yml

Tags: ruby, database, deployment, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano

When I try to deploy my app with capistrano, I'll get this error:

> failed: "sh -c 'cp
>   /var/www/my_app/releases/20120313115055/config/database.staging.yml
>   /var/www/my_app/releases/20120313115055/config/database.yml'" on
>   IP_ADDR

My **database.yml** ie empty, **database.staging.yml**:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: my_db
  pool: 15
  username: my_user_name
  password: my_pass
  host: localhost
```

in the **/confing/deploy** are files "production" "staging"

What am I missing here/where should I look for a failure? The credentials to database on the server should be right.

**EDIT** - here is my deploy

```
set :application, "my_app"
set :repository, "https://IP_ADDR/svn/my_app"

set :scm, :subversion
set :scm_username, 'my_name'
set :scm_password, 'my_pass'

default_run_options[:pty] = true

set :user, "my_name"
set :domain, 'IP_ADDR'

set :deploy_to, "/var/www/my_app"

set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
#set :keep_releases, 1

set :rails_env, 'production'

role :web, domain
role :app, domain
role :db,   domain, :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run

namespace :deploy do

    task :build_gems, :roles => :app do
        desc "Building gems"
        run "cd #{release_path} && bundle install --deployment"
    end

    task :migrations do
        desc "Migrating database"
        run "cd #{release_path} && rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production"
    end

    [:start, :stop].each do |t|
        desc "#{t} task is a no-op with passenger"
        task t, :roles => :app do ; end
    end

    desc "Restarting passenger with restart.txt"
    task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
        run "touch #{release_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
    end

    after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:build_gems", "db:copy_configuration", "config:copy", "deploy:migrations", "deploy:cleanup"
    after "deploy:update", "bluepill:copy_config", "bluepill:restart"
end

namespace :db do
    task :copy_configuration do
        run "cp #{release_path}/config/database.staging.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
    end
end

namespace :config do
    task :copy do
        run "cp #{release_path}/config/config.staging.yml #{release_path}/config/config.yml"
    end
end

namespace :bluepill do
  desc "Restart bluepill process"
  task :restart, :roles => [:app] do
    run "#{release_path}/script/delayed_job stop"
    sudo "/etc/init.d/bluepill.sh restart"
  end

  #desc "Load bluepill configuration and start it"
  ##task :start, :roles => [:app] do
   # sudo "/etc/init.d/bluepill.sh start"
  #end

  desc "Prints bluepills monitored processes statuses"
  task :status, :roles => [:app] do
    sudo "bluepill status"
  end

  desc "Copy config"
  task :copy_config, :roles => [:app] do
    run "cp #{release_path}/config/bluepill/configuration.rb /srv/script/bluepill.rb"
  end
end
```

The problem:

```
cp: cannot stat `/var/www/my_app/releases/20120313144907/config/database.staging.yml': No such file or directory
```

Comment: what happens when you run the cp command manually on that machine?

Comment: .yml or .ymp?   If you have .ymp your file is named wrong

Comment: when I try it to run in the terminal on the server, so I get the error  **No such file or directory**, and when I take a look into the **releases** directory, so that's empty.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm not sure how to solve your problem. It looks like database.staging.yml is not being deployed, so there's nothing for it to copy over.

I think there's a better workflow, though. Things like settings and database configs do not typically change between deployments, so those things can go in the shared folder of all the capistrano releases. Typically, you don't want your database.yml to be in your repo either since it's sensitive information. You can satisfy both of these things by excluding `config/database.yml` in your `.gitignore`.

This requires you to do a one time set up on your servers. You need create a `database.yml` at `your_app_path/shared/config`. Shared is a sibling to current and releases.

Your `deploy.rb` should have a task that symlinks the newly deployed release's `database.yml` to the on in the shared directory. Like this:

```
before "deploy:assets:precompile" do
  run ["ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/settings.yml #{release_path}/config/settings.yml",
       "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml",
       "ln -fs #{shared_path}/uploads #{release_path}/uploads"
  ].join(" && ")
end
```

This means that your repo will contain no `database.yml` files. Since they are probably already in your repo. You'll have to `git rm` them, commit. Add them to the `.gitignore` and commit that.

Comment: we did this, but included a database.yml.example in config, which developers can use to get going locally without having to guess at the database.yml settings

Comment: I think current/config/database.yml is linked to shared/config/database.yml If shared/config/database.yml is missing it will give you 'No such file or directory'. We can create it manually to shared/config/database.yml and deploy it. This stuff works here.

Comment: Sorry, why does your `deploy.rb` script mention `settings.yml`?

Answer (score 13):

In Capistrano 3, linking files is built-in. John's answer is simply:

- In the `shared/` folder create `config/database.yml`
- In `config/deploy.rb` use this line

  ```
  set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml')
  ```

This does what John was saying.

Comment: This is it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to "reference application objects or methods"([1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)) during precompile then you might be OK with setting `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile` to `false` in `config/application.rb`